# MVC Mini Profiler includes not respecting application's path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, mvc-mini-profiler

I've got the MVC Mini Profiler set up as described on its [project page](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/), and the includes are indeed being written on the page.

Problem is, my application sits at `http://localhost:8080/web`, and the markup written by the profiler includes looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/mini-profiler-includes.less?v=2.0.4177.17902">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mini-profiler-includes.js?v=2.0.4177.17902"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> jQuery(function() { MiniProfiler.init({ id:'fb4dc30e-c1aa-4be6-902c-ef2812dd1fe2', renderDirection:'left' }); } ); </script>
```

These all of course give 404 errors, but if I navigate to `/web/mini-profiler-includes.less?`, it loads fine.

The source that creates that string can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/browse/MvcMiniProfiler/UI/MiniProfilerHandler.cs):

```
// MiniProfilerHandler.cs
/// <summary>
/// Understands how to route and respond to MiniProfiler UI urls.
/// </summary>

public class MiniProfilerHandler : IRouteHandler, IHttpHandler
{
    internal static HtmlString RenderIncludes(MiniProfiler profiler, RenderPosition? position = null, bool showTrivial = false, bool showTimeWithChildren = false)
    {
        const string format =
            @"<link rel=""stylesheet/less"" type=""text/css"" href=""{0}mini-profiler-includes.less?v={1}"">
            <script type=""text/javascript"" src=""{0}mini-profiler-includes.js?v={1}""></script>
            <script type=""text/javascript""> jQuery(function() {{ MiniProfiler.init({{ id:'{2}', path:'{0}', renderDirection:'{3}', showTrivial: {4}, showChildrenTime: {5} }}); }} ); </script>";

        var pos = position ?? (MiniProfiler.Settings.RenderPopupButtonOnRight ? RenderPosition.Right : RenderPosition.Left);

        var result = profiler == null ? "" : string.Format(format,
                                                       EnsureEndingSlash(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath),
                                                       MiniProfiler.Settings.Version,
                                                       profiler.Id,
                                                       pos.ToString().ToLower(),
                                                       showTrivial ? "true" : "false",
                                                       showTimeWithChildren ? "true" : "false");

        return new HtmlString(result);
    }

    // rest of the code
}
```

Why isn't Request.ApplicationPath returning my application's path? Am I doing something wrong, or should I file an issue on the mvc-mini-profiler page?

**EDIT:** To make things even weirder, I put a breakpoint on the `MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()` call, and checked what the value of `HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath` was at that moment, and it was `"/web"`! Very mysterious.

**EDIT 2**: Looks like they may have added support for virtual paths in the latest version (2 hours ago :)), and the NuGet package (which is how I installed it) is not completely up to date. Investigating...

Comment: It's likely you, as [ApplicationPath exists for this sole purpose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx). That said, I think the profiler should be using `Url.Content()` rather than reinventing it. Does `Url.Content()` work correctly for you?

Comment: @Craig: Indeed, I use it all over the place.

Comment: If `Url.Content()` works and MVC Profiler doesn't, then I'd call it an MVC Profiler bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulling the latest source ([this commit](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/source/detail?r=4df727294f25174b8a54b6b5a1d7e9a2a795b845) being the most recent at time of this post), building the project, grabbing the DLL and referencing that instead of using the project's NuGet package fixed the problem.

**EDIT**: As of right now, the NuGet package is now up to date with the latest commit, so NuGet away!