# MVC-Mini-Profiler Error: yepnope is not defined

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler, yepnope

I am using the mvc-mini-profiler to profile my MVC site. It runs fine on my local machine, but when i publish to my hosting server, the profiler doesn't load, and i get the following error:

```
yepnope is not defined
yepnope([
```

As far as I can tell, the problem lies in the profiler trying to use yepnope before yepnope has been loaded. Is there a way around this, maybe by forcing a check to see if yepnope has been loaded before executing the miniprofile render command? Here are the relevant lines from the page's generated source

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/mini-profiler-yepnope.1.0.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
yepnope([
{ test: window.jQuery, nope: '/mini-profiler-jquery.1.6.1.js' },
```

And for completeness, the calls in my _layout file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes(position: RenderPosition.Left, showTrivial: false, showTimeWithChildren: false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this problem, it has been submitted to their google code project. It is a known issue, and they are working on it.

[Issue Page if you want to track it](http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/issues/detail?id=45)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are getting a 404 error when trying to load yepnope.js. There was a bug in MvcProfiler in dealing with application path, which has been addressed
in later builds.

[MVC Mini Profiler includes not respecting application's path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308890/mvc-mini-profiler-includes-not-respecting-applications-path)

Comment: I was under the impression that I didn't need to load yepnope, that that was included in the DLL

Comment: You don't need to load it. Please check if the profiler used the correct path to the yepnope.js when it rendered the includes. If not, just download the latest nuget package and you should be fine.

Comment: I have the latest NuGet package now, still no change.

Comment: This is the path it is using: src="/mini-profiler-yepnope.1.0.1.js"

Comment: What is the application path? Usually, it is src="<appPath>/mini-profiler-yepnope.1.0.1.js". check in firebug if you are getting a 404 for yepnope.js when you load the page. If yes, it probably indicates the the path is wrong.

Comment: I am getting a 404. Where can I check the appPath, and how would i go about forcing it to load properly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you aren't clearing your routes when registering them for your site.  The mini profiler adds its own routes for those javascript files to the RouteCollection potentially before your site is initialized.

Comment: I've looked through my global.asax, and all the default routing code is in there, I'm not clearing anything.